# In kubernetes not able to attach to container in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am not able to attach to a container in a pod. Receiving below message
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "sleep-76df4f989c-mqvnb" is forbidden: cannot exec into or attach to a privileged container

Could someone please let me what i am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a permission (possibly [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)) issue.
See [Kubernetes pod security-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/).

For instance [`gluster/gluster-kubernetes` issue 432](https://github.com/gluster/gluster-kubernetes/issues/432) points to [Azure PR 1961](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/pull/1961), which disable the  `cluster-admin` rights (although you can [customize/override the admission-controller flags passed to the API server](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/issues/2200#issuecomment-363070771)).

So it depends on the nature of your Kubernetes environment.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enabled RBAC at all. What I have done is that i have enabled istio and all the pods are now running with side car. 
I am not able to attach or exec to pods which have istio.
I am able to attach or exec which do not have istio proxy side car.

Need help here.